# What are some good resources to learn about automatic, learning based document summarization?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Document summarization can be done by text extraction from the source document *or* you can employ learning algorithms to decipher what's conveyed by the document, and then *generate* the summary using language generation techniques (much like a human does).

Are there algorithms or existing research work for the latter method? In general, what are some good resources to learn about document summarization techniques?

Answer (score 4):

The topic you are looking for is called [Automatic Summarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) in computer science community.

> Automatic summarization is the process of reducing a text document with a computer program in order to create a summary that retains the most important points of the original document.
>
> Methods of automatic summarization include extraction-based, abstraction-based, maximum entropy-based, and aided summarization.

Here is a good [survey](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nasmith/LS2/das-martins.07.pdf) paper on this topic. You might want to take a look at two other papers: [1](http://www.singhal.info/acl-isst97.pdf) and [2](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~nenkova/1500000015-Nenkova.pdf) as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically looking for abstraction-based summarization algorithms (not extraction based). Thanks for these resources, I'll go through them. But there seems to be very little research work on abstraction based summarization and not much online help to be found..

Comment: @sanjeevmk did you ever find more information on abstractive summarization? I'm interested in finding tools to assist in this as well, and so far the research has been thin.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic text summarisation is generally of two types: Abstractive and Extractive. Abstractive approach is a bit complicated than Extractive. In the first one, important features, key information from sentences are extracted. Using natural language generation techniques, new sentences are generated using those features.

However, in later approach, all the sentences are ranked using methods like Lexical Ranking, lexical chaining etc. The similar sentences are clustered using approaches like cosine similarity, fuzzy matching etc. The most important sentences of the clusters are used to generate a summary of given document.

Some existing Automatic document text summarisation work and techniques compiled from various sources:

1. [Semantria method of lexical chaining](https://semantria.com/features/summarization)
2. [MEAD](http://www.summarization.com/mead/)
3. http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=81789
4. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~afm/Home_files/Das_Martins_survey_summarization.pdf
5. http://www.upf.edu/pdi/iula/iria.dacunha/docums/cicling2013LNCS.pdf